# Application WorksheetFunction VLookup second variable

Tags: vba, class, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am completely stuck!  Previously I have used the below vlookup VBA in order to get my results.
For example:

```
Worksheets("Part Numbers").Cells(i + 1, 2) = _
                "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Supplier'!C[-2]:C[1],3,0)
```

I now need to use the Application Worksheet Function in order for the cell to contain the result (number) and not the function.  Here is what I have so far:

```
For i = 3 To LR ' last row 
    LUvalue = Worksheets("Part Numbers").Cells(i + 1, 2)  
    Worksheets("Part Numbers").Cells(i + 1, 3) = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LUvalue, [Supplier_Range], 3, False)
Next I
```

In have also included the below Error statement as I have read that this can sometime cause issues if not specified:

```
If IsError(Worksheets("Part Numbers").Cells(i + 1, 3)) Then

    Worksheets("Part Numbers").Cells(i + 1, 3) = "NA"

End If
```

When I run this I get the error 'unable to get vlookup property of worksheetfunction class'.  When I debug I can see that my LUValue is simply not right.  Essentially this should be the cell left of the cell I am putting the VLOOKUP into. I have also tried using an Offset for my LUValue and still can't get that to work either.  I believe the lookup value is where I am going wrong but honestly I am not sure as it all looks right to my eyes.

If anyone can offer some tips or guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your first code block you're putting the formula into Col B: in the next block you're reading `LUvalue` from Col B and putting the lookup result into Col C.  Has your column layout changed?

Comment: Yes sorry I'd tried a few things and added a couple of columns to test.  I hadn't cleaned it up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Dim sht As WorkSheet, res

Set sht = Worksheets("Part Numbers")

For i = 3 To LR ' last row 
    LUvalue = sht.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value  

    'adjust Supplier range to suit...
    res = Application.Vlookup(LUvalue, _
                              Worksheets("Supplier").Range("A:D"), _
                              3, False)

    sht.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Iif(iserror(res),"NA", res)

Next i
```